# How to pass a pre-defined value in a SQL script?

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

I am a beginner in Script writing in MySQL. I want to know how to pass a particular value for all of my script. In this I am updating values in all my tables between A63566 & A63570 by incriminating 1. Here I want to pass A63566 & A63570 value only one time for all my tables not to write for every individual script.

```
UPDATE SKPRT.FPL_TAR
SET CO_ID = concat('A',(SUBSTR(CO_ID,2,5) + 1))
WHERE CO_ID BETWEEN 'A63566' AND 'A63570';
COMMIT;
UPDATE SKPRT.QCS_STAT
SET CO_ID = concat('A',(SUBSTR(CO_ID,2,5) + 1))
WHERE CO_ID BETWEEN 'A63566' AND 'A63570';
COMMIT;
UPDATE SKPRT.REP_TM
SET CO_ID = concat('A',(SUBSTR(CO_ID,2,5) + 1))
WHERE CO_ID BETWEEN 'A63566' AND 'A63570';
COMMIT;
UPDATE SKPRT.CP_DATA
SET CO_ID = concat('A',(SUBSTR(CO_ID,2,5) + 1))
WHERE CO_ID BETWEEN 'A63566' AND 'A63570';
COMMIT;
UPDATE SKPRT.PNP_DATA
SET CO_ID = concat('A',(SUBSTR(CO_ID,2,5) + 1))
WHERE CO_ID BETWEEN 'A63566' AND 'A63570';
COMMIT;
UPDATE SKPRT.TLL_DATA
SET CO_ID = concat('A',(SUBSTR(CO_ID,2,5) + 1))
WHERE CO_ID BETWEEN 'A63566' AND 'A63570';
COMMIT;
```

Comment: You could possibly do something with a procedure, information_schema.tables and dynamic sql.

Comment: if you use mysql whyt do you use oracle tags?

Comment: I have removed the oracle tags.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this

```
drop table if exists t1,t2;
create table t1(co_id varchar(10));
create table t2(co_id varchar(10));
insert into t1 values ('a1'),('b1'),('a2'),('a3'),('a4');
insert into t2 values ('a1'),('b1'),('a2'),('a3'),('a4');
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
create procedure p(in1 varchar(10),in2 varchar(10))
begin
declare tablename varchar(10);
declare done int;
declare cur cursor for select table_name from information_schema.columns where table_name in('t1','t2');
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    open cur;
    cursorloop:loop
    fetch cur into tablename;
    if done = true then  
        leave cursorloop;
    end if;  

    set @sql = 
     (select concat('
     UPDATE ', tablename,'
        SET CO_ID = concat(',char(39),'A',char(39),',(SUBSTR(CO_ID,2,1) + 1))
        WHERE CO_ID BETWEEN ', char(39),in1,char(39), ' AND ', char(39),in2,char(39)
        )
     )  ;
     select @sql;
     prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
     execute sqlstmt;
     deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
    end loop cursorloop;
    close cur;
end $$

delimiter ;
call p('a1','a3');
```

Where we pick the tables of interest from information_schema.tables an build a prepared statement(s)